# Whats the difference between ./webapp.py and python webapp.py

Tags: python

I have started with python n flask few days ago. I was just trying to run a python file  `webapp.py` on a `terminal` with following code but got errors:

```
$ ./webapp.py 
from: can't read /var/mail/flask
from: can't read /var/mail/flask
./webapp.py: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./webapp.py: line 3: `app = Flask(__name__)'
```

But it runs successfully with the command:

```
$ python webapp.py 
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
```

**webapp.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

As a part of curiosity,

- Whats the difference between `./webapp.py` and `python webapp.py`?

Comment: It's definitely a duplicate, but not of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running a python script directly (without specifying the interpreter in the command), you need to tell the shell which interpreter will process the script, e.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
```

This first line is often referred to as "[shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))".

Comment: Only a small extension. The file has to be executable: `chmod +x webapp.py`. When calling it like this: `python webapp.py`, it doesn't need to be executable.

Comment: Good point. Although it seems that the file is already an executable.